# Dagger2, providing Retrofit instances with different URLs

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Currently I'm using Dagger 2 to inject an instance of Retrofit to use for an api call in a widget. From my understanding, Dagger searches for things to inject using the type, so declaring 2 seperate `@Provides Retrofit providesRetrofit()` with different names wouldn't work.

Heres my current code:

Module:

```
@Module
public class ApiModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    GsonConverterFactory provideGson() {
        return GsonConverterFactory.create();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    RxJavaCallAdapterFactory provideRxCallAdapter() {
        return RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Retrofit providePictureRetrofit(GsonConverterFactory gsonConverterFactory, RxJavaCallAdapterFactory rxJavaCallAdapterFactory) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(MarsWeatherWidget.PICTURE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(rxJavaCallAdapterFactory)
                .build();
        return retrofit;
    }

....
//Here is the other Retrofit instance where I was wanting to use a different URL.

//    @Singleton
//    @Provides
//    Retrofit provideWeatherRetrofit(GsonConverterFactory gsonConverterFactory, RxJavaCallAdapterFactory rxJavaCallAdapterFactory) {
//        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
//                .baseUrl(MarsWeatherWidget.WEATHER_URL)
//                .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
//                .addCallAdapterFactory(rxJavaCallAdapterFactory)
//                .build();
//        return retrofit;
//    }
}
```

Component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApiModule.class)
public interface ApiComponent {

    void inject (MarsWeatherWidget marsWeatherWidget);

}
```

class extending `Application`:

```
public class MyWidget extends Application {

    ApiComponent mApiComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mApiComponent = DaggerApiComponent.builder().apiModule(new ApiModule()).build();
    }

    public ApiComponent getApiComponent() {
        return mApiComponent;
    }
}
```

and finally where im actually injecting it:

```
@Inject Retrofit pictureRetrofit;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        mAppWidgetIds = appWidgetIds;
        ((MyWidget) context.getApplicationContext()).getApiComponent().inject(this);
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);
        }
    }

......
//use the injected Retrofit instance to make a call
```

So how can I organize this to give me a seperate Retrofit instance that is built with different URLs for hitting different APIs? Let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: Have you looked at scopes in Dagger2?

Comment: Did you have a look at `@Named` and maybe other Qualifiers?

Comment: @hoomi Well from what i've read scopes define how long an instance is kept around, eg an instance scoped to an `Acitivty` will survive as long as the activity, and one scoped to `Application` will survive with the application.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Just checked out `@Named` and added a `@Named` qualifier to the method in the module, and then used it when injecting. Seems to work. Is this the recommended approach for this situtation?

Comment: Yes. You could maybe use different components if you had logically independent parts, but most likely qualifiers are what you want and need.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Provide different versions of the same type

You can use `@Named` (or custom annotations that are annotated with `@Qualifier`) to distinguish between variants of the same type.

Add the annotations like the following:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
@Named("picture")
Retrofit providePictureRetrofit(GsonConverterFactory gsonConverterFactory, RxJavaCallAdapterFactory rxJavaCallAdapterFactory) {
    return retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(MarsWeatherWidget.PICTURE_URL) // one url
            .build();
}


@Singleton
@Provides
@Named("weather")
Retrofit provideWeatherRetrofit(GsonConverterFactory gsonConverterFactory, RxJavaCallAdapterFactory rxJavaCallAdapterFactory) {
    return retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(MarsWeatherWidget.WEATHER_URL) // other url
            .build();
}
```

### Custom `@Qualifier`

You could also just create a custom annotation like the following:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Picture {}
```

You would just use this instead of `@Named(String)`.

## Injecting the qualified version

When you have your module providing the qualified types, you just need to also add the qualifier where you need the dependency.

```
MyPictureService provideService(@Named("picture") Retrofit retrofit) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hey, really cool. Haven't worked yet with Dagger or any other DI, so one thing is not clear to me: this leads us to have two instances of retrofit, or just one? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, `@Qualifiers` are used to differentiate between multiple objects of the same type. This will leave you with multiple objects, which you can then inject independently. The `GsonConverterFactory` in the above sample would be shared, though.

Comment: If you are creating multiple instances of Retrofit, you must share a single OkHttp instance, else there will be performance degradation. 
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-share-okhttp-client-and-converters-between-retrofit-instances

Comment: @DavidMedenjak ... Can you please have a look at my case ... ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/54252764/1083093 )

Comment: Great. I was looking for it.

Answer (score 6):

You should use a *qualifier* annotation to distinguish between different objects that have the same type—like between the `Retrofit` for pictures and the `Retrofit` for weather.

You apply the same qualifier to the `@Provides` method and to the `@Inject` parameter (constructor or method parameter, or field).

`@Named` is one qualifier annotation, but using it means you have to remember to use the exact same string at the provision point and at all injection points. (It's easy to mistype `@Named("whether")` somewhere.)

But it's easy to define your own qualifier annotation. Just define a custom annotation type, and annotate that with [`@Qualifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Qualifier.html):

```
@Documented
@Qualifier
public @interface Picture {}

@Documented
@Qualifier
public @interface Weather {}
```

Then you can bind each `Retrofit` differently:

```
@Provides @Picture Retrofit providePictureRetrofit(…) {…}
@Provides @Weather Retrofit provideWeatherRetrofit(…) {…}
```

and inject each where you need it:

```
@Inject @Picture Retrofit pictureRetrofit;
@Inject @Weather Retrofit weatherRetrofit;
// (But constructor injection is better than field injection!)
```

Comment: Will have to try this as well, thanks for your input.